# Django admin inline: Clone entry

Tags: django, django-admin

I`m using a GenericStackedInline in my django admin. I would like to have the option to duplicate the inline object when editing the parent object.

I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. Using [django-inline-actions](https://pypi.org/project/django-inline-actions/) to add a "clone" button. This did not work, because it does not show when using a fieldset in the GenericStackedInline
2. Adding another checkbox next to "delete" checkbox with label "clone". When activating the checkbox and saving parent object, it should clone the inline object with new id. Is there an easy way to add another checkbox and add a action to handle cloning?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution. I don`t really like it. Biggest flaw in my oppinion is, that I did not find a way to do clone in InlineClass, Mixin or formset. It's a bit clumsy that two classes / Mixins need to be combined to handle it.

Improvements or other solutions are very welcome.

**Inline classes**

```
class RgCloneInlineFormset(BaseGenericInlineFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super().add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields["CLONE"] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

class RgGenericStackedInlineWithClone(GenericStackedInline):
    template = "admin/edit_inline/stacked_with_clone.html"
    formset = RgCloneInlineFormset

class DetailpageElementInline(RgGenericStackedInlineWithClone, RgImagePreviewMixin):
    model = DetailpageElement
    extra = 0
```

**Admin class**

```
class CloneDetailpageElementInlineMixin():

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        # Save formset
        ret = super().save_formset(request, form, formset, change)

        # Do clone if nessesary
        detailpage_ids_to_clone = []

        for data in formset.cleaned_data:
            if isinstance(data.get("id"), DetailpageElement):
                if data.get("CLONE"):
                    detailpage_ids_to_clone.append(data.get("id").id)

        for detailpage_element in DetailpageElement.objects.filter(id__in=detailpage_ids_to_clone):
            detailpage_element.id = None
            detailpage_element.save()
        
        # Make sure function works like super function
        return ret

@admin.register(ArticleInt)
class ArticleIntAdmin(CloneDetailpageElementInlineMixin, ContentAdminBase):
    inlines = [
        inlines.DetailpageElementInline,
    ]
```

**Template admin/edit_inline/stacked_with_clone.html**
Just copied the stacked.html from django source code and added
`{% if inline_admin_formset.has_add_permission and inline_admin_form.original %}<span class="clone">{{ inline_admin_form.form.CLONE }} Clone</span>{% endif %}`